# Can you calculate the time interval between 2 specific column values in KDB+(Q)?

Tags: kdb

I have a table with two columns: time, separation. My goal is to calculate the average time intervals that non-negative separation occurs over the table; so if separation is positive for a while and then switches to negative, I want the amount of time that separation remained positive to be stowed in another table (and vice versa). With a table fully built out of just time intervals where separation switched signs, I need to calculate the average of that.

I also would love to be able to stow the average value of separation over the specific time interval into the table and have it keyed with the length of the time interval.

Hoping to have an end table that has a magnitude of time interval in one column (i.e. 00:00:04.129) and the average value of the separation in that interval (something like +0.0014).

So, how can I grab a time range where the separation column is + or -, and match that with the average value of separation over that period?

Comment: Can you produce a small example to highlight what you expect? This should help guide the answers.

Comment: The table is currently time (DateTime) by separation (float), and I want to produce a table that has the amount of time it takes for separation to revert back to 0 whenever it's positive or negative and the corresponding avg. value of separation over that interval.

Comment: Like: time of separation persistence column: 00:00:01.123, 00:00:14.123, 00:00:05.123..., Average separation over period: 0.0012, -1.123, 0.957, ... etc. with each avg. sep. value matching the separation time that it persisted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following small snippet of an example table used to calculate avg separation per period of positive separation:

```
q)show tab:([]time:asc 20?03:00:00;sep:(20?1 -1)*20?1f)
time     sep
-------------------
00:18:02 0.6425202
00:30:59 0.5666474
00:43:05 0.2966318
...
```

The following function has 2 steps, first is to get time difference between ticks and then sum time and get the average separation of groups of continuous rows of positive or negative separation (first statement). From this the output can be filtered to give only those rows that had positive separation.

```
q)f:{t:select sum time,avg sep by sums differ sep>0 from update deltas time from x;select time,sep from t where sep>0}
q)f tab
time     sep
-------------------
00:12:06 0.5019331
00:00:23 0.04909149
00:07:14 0.9275499
00:08:45 0.4221353
00:07:05 0.7766876
```

To repeat for negative you can replace `>0` with `<0`. I was unsure of how you would like zeroes handled so I used `>0` instead of `signum`.

Comment: When I tried this I had outputs in the time column >06:30:00.000 which is larger than my complete time range for the table (9:30-4 pm). Any clues as to why? this feels so close to perfect, I just can't figure out that part.

Comment: Sounds like your time column is actual time rather than time difference like I have assumed. The fix for that should be to use `deltas time` instead of `time`. Note `deltas` can also be used as a binary function with the initial value set, like `deltas[time 0;time]`

Comment: No problem, going to update my answer to add in `deltas`